# On what basis does the Appengine location headers tell the location?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, http-headers, location

I have hosted my Web app on Google Appengine. At times I need to know the location of the visitors. So I have been using the request headers provided by Google:

```
        String visitorCountry = request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Country");
        String visitorRegion = request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-Region");       
        String visitorCity = request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-City");
        String visitorLatLong = request.getHeader("X-AppEngine-CityLatLong");
```

They have never been accurate to the location, and I guess it tells me the location of the ISP. On what basis does the Google Appengine's request headers work? Is it primarily on the IP address the client sends along the request?

Here are the [header docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Request_Headers) for reference.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Request_Headers. I'd think it would be hard to pinpoint exactly, since the ISP's control the location that an IP points to. Great question.

Comment: @jmort253 Actually I wanted to know how this is different from _HTML5 goelocation_ feature

Answer (score 2):

People can go here - http://mylocationtest.appspot.com/ - and see what location information comes up for them.

For me, the lat/long are just the nominal center of the city listed - about 20km from my actual location.  The ISP is Rogers Canada.

Apparently, sometimes country comes back as 'ZZ'.
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5296

This IP address information is usually packaged with the [ASN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_%28Internet%29).  This tells you the ISP, and as someone mentioned above, only they can say where one of their IP's is assigned.  Perhaps the accuracy of the location information depends on the ISP.

(This isn't an answer to the question - just further discussion - but it didn't really work in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, using the HTML5 Geolocation feature tends to be more accurate than the IP based location detection. This will be especially so when you use your mobile web site on GPS enabled devices and if you have enabled high accuracy.

Check out this post too for a good discussion on the two approaches : [Why HTML5 Geolocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541779/why-html5-geolocation)

Comment: but the question is _On what basis does the Appengine location headers tell the location?_

Comment: The documentation says "App Engine determines the country code,etc from the client's IP address". As jmort253 mentioned the ISP's control the location that the IP points to.