# Can a request's geographical location be known in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting some malicious requests to my GAE Node.js HTTP 1.1 endpoints.  I know they are malicious because the only requests to these endpoints should come from mobile devices, but the requests use "Chrome 72" user-agent and wrongly use GET on POST endpoints.

The requests routinely target random APIs. They haven't caused any damage, but I wonder if I can know more about who is behind these requests. The Logger doesn't show geographical origin/ip adress AFAIK, does it? Is there any other way to know this? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: See location headers here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/request-response-headers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On what basis does the Appengine location headers tell the location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109831/on-what-basis-does-the-appengine-location-headers-tell-the-location)

Comment: Excellent answer and it works. Thank you

Comment: (first answer was enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned by @gaefan, you can find geographical information of an API request sender using the Location Headers described in the [App Engine Dodcumentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/reference/request-response-headers).